# ajax POST method gets "HTML" data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am unable to get the string variable from servlet through AJAX call, I am getting the HTML data (of resultant jsp page on success of email and password as responseText). Below is the code used
LoginServlet code: (doPOST)

```
        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass  = request.getParameter("pass");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        session.setAttribute("uname", request.getParameter("uname"));
        session.setAttribute("pass", request.getParameter("pass"));
        LOGGER.info("This is Login Servlet");
        LoginDao dao = new LoginDao();
        Boolean a = dao.check(uname, pass);
        System.out.println("hello " + a);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        if(a) {
            session.setAttribute("uname", uname);
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            out.write("success");
        } 
        else {
            //response.getWriter().write(urlOnFailure);
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write("Fail");
        }
```

}

Test.jsp :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form id="login_form"  method="post">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>UserName </td> 
   <td> <input type="text" id="email" name="uname"  autocomplete="off"> </td>      
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>Password </td> 
   <td> <input type="password" id = "password" name="pass"  autocomplete="off"> </td>
   <td> <a href="forgotPassword.jsp">Forgot password? </a><br> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <a href="register.jsp">New User? signUp here </a>
 <input id="button1" type="button" value="Click Me" />
</form>
<a href="forgotPassword.jsp" id ="myBtn">Forgot password? </a>
<script src="./loginTest.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function(responseText){
 var email = $('#email').val();
 var password = $('#password').val();
 $.ajax({
   async: false,
   type:'POST',
   url:'LoginServlet',
   data: {"uname":email,"pass":password},
   success:function(responseText){
   //window.location = data.url;
    alert(responseText);
    alert('Success in JS');
   /*window.location.href = "welcome.jsp";
   //$(location).attr('href','welcome.jsp');
   if(responseText== null){
   window.location.href = "login.jsp";}*/
   },
  });
 });
});
```

Requirement: 
1) Need the value of variable 'a' from servlet, which tells login is successful or not in ajax responseText.
2) Based on responseText redirect to required JSP pages.[if a=1 welcome.jsp else login.jsp]

Comment: what is the  value of **responseText**  ? you are getting ?

Comment: I am getting html data in response text

Comment: **success** or  **fail** you mean?

Comment: Hi Swati, Thanks for looking into it, I was able to get correct data. Issue is not with my code. My java build was not success. I have recreated a new project with same files and now I am able to get correct result.